# BeautifulSoup for multiple URLs with different templates

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape multiple URLs with 2 different HTML templates. I can scrape each HTML by itself without issue, but I ran into a problem when trying to combine the two scrapers. Below is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page_url1 = 'https://www.vet.upenn.edu/research/centers-laboratories/research-laboratory/research-laboratory/anguera-laboratory'
page_url2 = 'https://www.med.upenn.edu/apps/faculty/index.php/g20001100/p8866286'
page_url_lst = {'url': [page_url1, page_url2], 'template': [1,2]}
page_url_df = pd.DataFrame(page_url_lst)

data = []
if page_url_df['template'] == 1:
    for url in page_url_df['url']:
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        for e in soup.select('#tabs-publications em'):
            data.append({
                'author':e.previous.get_text(strip=True)[:-1],
                'title':e.get_text(strip=True),
                'journal':e.next_sibling.get_text(strip=True),
                'source': url
            })
else:
    for url_2 in page_url_df['url']:
        r_2 = requests.get(url_2)
        soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(r_2.text, 'lxml')
        for a in soup_2.find_all('span',{'class':'fac_citation'}):
            data.append({
                'author':a.find('b').get_text(),
                'title':a.find('i').get_text(strip=True),
                'journal':a.find('i').next_sibling.get_text(strip=True),
                'source': url_2
            })
```

The logic here if the column 'template' returns a value of 1, then extract the data using the first template, else extract the data using the second template. However, this code return this error: `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to create new dataframe based on `page_url_df`:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page_url1 = "https://www.vet.upenn.edu/research/centers-laboratories/research-laboratory/research-laboratory/anguera-laboratory"
page_url2 = (
    "https://www.med.upenn.edu/apps/faculty/index.php/g20001100/p8866286"
)
page_url_lst = {"url": [page_url1, page_url2], "template": [1, 2]}
page_url_df = pd.DataFrame(page_url_lst)


def get_template_1(url):
    data = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")
    for e in soup.select("#tabs-publications em"):
        data.append(
            {
                "author": e.previous.get_text(strip=True)[:-1],
                "title": e.get_text(strip=True),
                "journal": e.next_sibling.get_text(strip=True),
                "source": url,
            }
        )
    return data


def get_template_2(url):
    data = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")
    for a in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "fac_citation"}):
        data.append(
            {
                "author": a.find("b").get_text(),
                "title": a.find("i").get_text(strip=True),
                "journal": a.find("i").next_sibling.get_text(strip=True),
                "source": url,
            }
        )
    return data


all_data = []
for _, row in page_url_df.iterrows():
    print("Getting", row["url"])
    if row["template"] == 1:
        all_data.extend(get_template_1(row["url"]))
    elif row["template"] == 2:
        all_data.extend(get_template_2(row["url"]))


df_out = pd.DataFrame(all_data)

# print sample data
print(df_out.head().to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | author | title | journal | source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Hantsoo Liisa, Kornfield Sara, Anguera Montserrat C, Epperson C Neill | Inflammation: A Proposed Intermediary Between Maternal Stress and Offspring Neuropsychiatric Risk. [PMID30314641] | Biological psychiatry 85(2): 97-106, Jan 2019. | https://www.vet.upenn.edu/research/centers-laboratories/research-laboratory/research-laboratory/anguera-laboratory |
| 1 | Sierra Isabel, Anguera Montserrat C | Enjoy the silence: X-chromosome inactivation diversity in somatic cells.[PMID31108425] | Current opinion in genetics & development 55: 26-31, May 2019. | https://www.vet.upenn.edu/research/centers-laboratories/research-laboratory/research-laboratory/anguera-laboratory |
| 2 | Syrett Camille M, Anguera Montserrat C | When the balance is broken: X-linked gene dosage from two X chromosomes and female-biased autoimmunity. [PMID31125996] | Journal of leukocyte biology May 2019. | https://www.vet.upenn.edu/research/centers-laboratories/research-laboratory/research-laboratory/anguera-laboratory |
| 3 | Kotzin Jonathan J, Iseka Fany, Wright Jasmine, Basavappa Megha G, Clark Megan L, Ali Mohammed-Alkhatim, Abdel-Hakeem Mohamed S, Robertson Tanner F, Mowel Walter K, Joannas Leonel, Neal Vanessa D, Spencer Sean P, Syrett Camille M, Anguera Montserrat C, Williams Adam, Wherry E John, Henao-Mejia Jorge | The long noncoding RNA regulates CD8 T cells in response to viral infection.[PMID31138702] | Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America 116(24): 11916-11925, Jun 2019. | https://www.vet.upenn.edu/research/centers-laboratories/research-laboratory/research-laboratory/anguera-laboratory |
| 4 | Syrett Camille M, Paneru Bam, Sandoval-Heglund Donavon, Wang Jianle, Banerjee Sarmistha, Sindhava Vishal, Behrens Edward M, Atchison Michael, Anguera Montserrat C | Altered X-chromosome inactivation in T cells may promote sex-biased autoimmune diseases. [PMID30944248 | JCI insight 4(7), Apr 2019. | https://www.vet.upenn.edu/research/centers-laboratories/research-laboratory/research-laboratory/anguera-laboratory |

Answer (score 2):

You need an iterable in an outer loop. One way would be to generate a tuple list from your existing dataframe columns and loop that. You can then have your conditional logic, simplified, within the loop.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page_url1 = "https://www.vet.upenn.edu/research/centers-laboratories/research-laboratory/research-laboratory/anguera-laboratory"
page_url2 = "https://www.med.upenn.edu/apps/faculty/index.php/g20001100/p8866286"
page_url_lst = {"url": [page_url1, page_url2], "template": [1, 2]}
page_url_df = pd.DataFrame(page_url_lst)

data = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    for template, url in zip(
        page_url_df["template"].to_list(), page_url_df["url"].to_list()
    ):
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

        if template == 1:
           
            for e in soup.select("#tabs-publications em"):
                data.append(
                    {
                        "author": e.previous.get_text(strip=True)[:-1],
                        "title": e.get_text(strip=True),
                        "journal": e.next_sibling.get_text(strip=True),
                        "source": url,
                    }
                )
        else:

            for a in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "fac_citation"}):
                data.append(
                    {
                        "author": a.find("b").get_text(),
                        "title": a.find("i").get_text(strip=True),
                        "journal": a.find("i").next_sibling.get_text(strip=True),
                        "source": url,
                    }
                )
print(data)
```

Comment: Grats to golden `beautifulsoup` badge :) Let's get the `html` one too!